# How clear cache after commit Symfony project in PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm, symfony

Is there an automatic way to clear cache for both environments just after commit and pushing files in PhpStorm?

Comment: I don't know about PhpStorm but you can create your own [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks). Also this is a full example [Git pre-push hook example for php-cs-fixer](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/x4pq/git-pre-push-hook-example-for-php-cs-fixer) which would help you to start writing yours. It should be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to my comment above:

---

First of, all the [client side git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) samples are stored under `.git/hooks/` directory of your local project.

```
your_project$ ls -la .git/hooks/

drwxrwxr-x 2 myself myself 4096 Jan 11 16:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 myself myself 4096 Feb 21 16:13 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself  452 Sep  7 10:22 applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself  896 Sep  7 10:22 commit-msg.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself  189 Sep  7 10:22 post-update.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself  398 Sep  7 10:22 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself 1642 Sep  7 10:22 pre-commit.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself 1239 Sep  7 10:22 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself 1352 Sep  7 10:22 pre-push.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself 4898 Sep  7 10:22 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myself myself 3611 Sep  7 10:22 update.sample
```

**EXAMPLE**

This example will clear local `test` environment cache before committing the changes so using `pre-commit` hook. If you want, you can adjust it to your needs.

**1. Create pre-commit hook.**

```
your_project$ sudo nano .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

**2. Update hook content.** *(Your path might be `./bin/console` instead)*

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f ./app/console ]
then
    ./app/console cache:clear --env=test
fi
```

**3. Assign executable permissions.**

```
your_project$ sudo chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

**TEST**

[image]